# How to change theme for magento multiple store?

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, theme, configuration, backend

I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2.

I follow this [**Tutorial**](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-set-up-and-manage-multiple-stores.html) for creating the website on my local machine.

```
Default magento url is: http://localhost/magento

My new site URL is: http://localhost/magento/newsite
```

Now I have to change the **"THEME"** for the new site.

I've tried these methods:

**Method 1:**

1. system -> configuration
2. Change the current configuration scope  to my new site.
3. General -> Design ->theme (give the theme name modern for Templates

**Method 2:**

1. system -> Design -> Add design
2. select my site and theme (modern)

But the theme didn't change it always take the theme which I gave for the default config.

How to set the Different theme for different site form single back-end.

Is there any way to change the theme?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer,
**i make mistake here.**

In the new store **"index.php"** file u need to change the content like.

```
umask(0);
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '<your site code>';
/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'website';
```

Now i fix the issue.

Cheers.